# Spring Boot JPA Native Query Object Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Model called CommunityProfile. This model contains two child relationships; player (type User), and rank (type Rank).

The default spring boot JPA-generated query is taking approximately 9s to fetch 200 records, which is rather slow. By using the following MySQL query, I can return the data I need rather quickly:

```
SELECT cp.*, r.*, u.* FROM community_profiles cp
LEFT JOIN users u ON cp.player_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN ranks r ON cp.rank_id = r.id 
WHERE cp.community_id = 1
```

How can I make my repository map the results to their correct Objects/Models?

I have tried using a non-native query, like this:

```java
    @Query("SELECT cp FROM CommunityProfile cp " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH cp.player u " +
            "LEFT JOIN FETCH cp.rank r " +
            "WHERE cp.communityId = :communityId")
    List<CommunityProfile> findByCommunityIdWithJoin(@Param("communityId") Integer communityId);
```

However, this is still quite slow in comparison, resulting in an 800-900ms response. For comparison, my current Laravel application can return the same data in a 400-ms cold start.

Any tips are appreciated, thank you

==UPDATE==

After trying the suggested @Index annotation, I still don't really see any performance gains. Did I implement correctly?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "community_profiles", indexes = @Index(name = "cp_ci_idx", columnList = "community_id"))
public class CommunityProfile {
```

Answer (score 1):

If your JPA query is working, and you are just asking about performance, you may add the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON community_profiles(community_id);
```

This index should allow MySQL to filter off records which are not part of the result set.

From JPA itself you may use:

```java
@Table(indexes = @Index(name = "idx", columnList = "community_id"))
public class CommunityProfile {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I know this needs ran on the database, but is there a tidy spring boot way of ensuring it’s automatically ran (ie if connected to a blank database)

Comment: Use the `@Index` annotation.

Comment: So I gave this a go, check my updated post. Didn't see any performance increase

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ***EntityManager***

```
       @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
             private EntityManager entityManager;

            List<CommunityProfile> findByCommunityIdWithJoin(Integer communityId){
              String query = ""SELECT cp FROM CommunityProfile cp " +
                    "LEFT JOIN FETCH cp.player u " +
                    "LEFT JOIN FETCH cp.rank r " +
                    "WHERE cp.communityId = :communityId"
            List<CommunityProfile> list = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, CommunityProfile.class)
                            .setParameter("communityId",communityId)
                            .getResultList();
           entityManager.clear();
           return list
        }
```

Once I used this kind of native query inside loop and it constantly returned cash values bu *entityManagaer.clear()* clears cash. This is for info only)

Or create an [Index](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-indexes) on specific columns when you are defining entity classes like:

```
  @Table(indexes = {
  @Index(columnList = "firstName"),
  @Index(name = "fn_index", columnList = "firstName"),
  @Index(name = "mulitIndex1", columnList = "firstName, lastName")
  ...
}
```

For Non-entity @Index you can check [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/package-summary.html)